# Laravel where query for getting record if the difference of two fields is not 0

Tags: mysql, laravel

I need to get record only if subtraction of two fields is not zero.

```
$list = InspectionCertificate::where('amount' - 'billed_amount' != 0)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can you provide more information.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample code for that with Eloquent Model

```
$list = InspectionCertificate::whereRaw('(amount - billed_amount) > 0')->get();
```

You can use `whereRaw` to pass raw query in Query Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing more info you will get a better answer, but here is a way using the query builder:

```
\DB::table('table_name')
    ->havingRaw('(column1 - column2) != 0')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Not Equal operator](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-equal-operator.php), you can able to do.

Sample query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName    
WHERE (ColumnName1 - ColumnName2) != 0
```